# Why drawed circle is not displayed on the map?

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers

My project based on OpenLayers 6.

I have a button location when it pressed the map to use animation to locate and draw a circle on the map where the user is located.

Here is the code:

```js
$("#locate").click(function() {

    let animations = new createAnimations();
    let geolocation = new ol.Geolocation({
        // enableHighAccuracy must be set to true to have the heading value.
        projection: map.getView().getProjection(),
        tracking: true,
        trackingOptions: {
            enableHighAccuracy: false,
            maximumAge: 0
        }
    });



    positionFeature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 6,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#3399CC'
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: '#fff',
                width: 2
            })
        })
    }));

    let coordinates = geolocation.getPosition();
    let point = new ol.geom.Point(coordinates);

    positionFeature.setGeometry(point ? point : null);
    animations.flyTo(coordinates, function() {});


    let locationLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        map: map,
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [positionFeature]
        })
    });
```

But the circle which I try to create on execution is not displayed on the map.
Any idea why I don't see the circle on the map?

Comment: You are missing a closing `});` and I get javascript errors with the posted code: `Uncaught ReferenceError: createAnimations is not defined` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: positionFeature is not defined`  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Are you running your map on a secure (`https:`) server?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this: https://www.geocodezip.net/OL_6.3.1_geolocation_20200707.html?

Comment: @geocodezip , thanks for post, yes I am trying to do similar that on the link.But why after the navigation to my current postion the map is locating  back to my position after move it?